# how to make hexagone button in python with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

for a project I have to create the hex game, and therefore I need to create buttons in the shape of a hexagon, and having searched on the internet I could not find a solution. Be careful, the hitbox of the button must also be a hexagon

Extra characters because I can't post at the moment: ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jan 15 16:16:24 2024

@author: shamiiow
"""
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Game(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        
        #0 : case vide
        #1 : case bleu 
        #2 : case rouge
        
        self.player = False
        self.couleur = ["white","blue", "red"]
        self.winner = 0
        self.recap = []
        self.longeur = 4 + 2
        self.grid_p = [[0 for _ in range(self.longeur)] for _ in range(self.longeur)]
        self.grid_w = [[0 for _ in range(self.longeur)] for _ in range(self.longeur)]
        
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = self.longeur - 2
        
        for i in range(self.longeur):
            for j in range(self.longeur):
                if (i == 0) or (j == 0) or (i == self.longeur-1) or (j == self.longeur-1):
                    self.grid_p[i][j] = 9
                    
        self.list_w = [[None for _ in range(1, self.longeur - 1)] for _ in range(1, self.longeur - 1)]
        for i in range(len(self.list_w)):
            for j in range(len(self.list_w[i])):
                print(i, j)
                self.list_w[i][j] = Button(text = f"{str(i+1)};{str(j+1)}")
                self.list_w[i][j].bind(on_press=lambda instance, x=i+1, y=j+1: self.play(instance, (x, y)))
                self.add_widget(self.list_w[i][j])
        
    def play(self, instance, c):
        print(self.winner)
        if self.winner != 0:
            self.update()
            return
        if self.grid_p[c[0]][c[1]] != 0:
            return
        self.grid_w = [[0 for _ in range(self.longeur)] for _ in range(self.longeur)]
        self.grid_p[c[0]][c[1]] = 1 + int(self.player)
        self.recap.append(c)
        self.update()
        self.win()
        self.player = self.player ^ True
    
    def win(self):
        self.grid_w = [[0 for _ in range(self.longeur)] for _ in range(self.longeur)]

        for i in range(1,self.longeur-1):
            if self.winner == 0:
                self.path((1 ,i), 1)
        self.grid_w = [[0 for _ in range(self.longeur)] for _ in range(self.longeur)]
        for i in range(1,self.longeur-1):
            if self.winner == 0:
                self.path((i, 1), 2)
    
    def path(self, c, p):
        x, y = c[0], c[1]
        if self.grid_p[x][y] != p:
            return 
        for i in [-1, 0, 1]:
            for j in [-1, 0, 1]:
                if [i, j] != [0, 0] and [i, j] != [-1, -1]and [i, j] != [1, 1]:
                    if self.grid_p[x+i][y+j] == p and self.grid_w[x+i][y+j] == 0:
                        self.grid_w[x+i][y+j] = 1
                        self.path((x+i, y+j), p)

        if (1 in self.grid_w[self.longeur-2] and p == 1) or (1 in [self.grid_w[i][self.longeur-2] for i in range(self.longeur)] and p == 2):
            self.winner = 1 + int(self.player)
            
    def update(self):
        if self.winner != 0:
            pass  #commande pour afficher la victoire
        for i in range(self.longeur):
            for j in range(self.longeur):
                if self.grid_p[i][j] == 0:
                    self.list_w[i-1][j-1].background_color = (1,1,1,1)
                if self.grid_p[i][j] == 1:
                    self.list_w[i-1][j-1].background_color = (0,0,1,1)
                if self.grid_p[i][j] == 2:
                    self.list_w[i-1][j-1].background_color = (1,0,0,1)
                    
                
                
    def affiche(self):
        for i in range(self.longeur):
            print(self.grid_p[i], self.grid_w[i])
        

class Hex(App):
    def build(self):
        return Game()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Hex().run()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's not a simple task. You will need to define your own custom `Widget` class (perhaps named `HexButton`) that uses `ButtonBehavior` and includes graphics instructions to draw the hexagon. Have a look at the `Button` rule in the `style.kv` file that is distributed with Kivy. Those instructions draw a rectangle, but you may need to draw triangles or a mesh. You will also need to over-ride the default `collide_point()` method to correctly determine if a point is inside the hexagon.